# How can I add scrollbars to a SkinnableContainer created runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, scrollbar, flex-spark

I created a SkinnableContainer runtime because I want to set some style properties to it, then based on some external data I need to create a new SkinnableContainer and add it as children of the first one. This children height can be greater than the parent container.

How can I create a SkinnableContainer runtime with some scrollbars?
I [read in the documentation that I need to create a new Skin](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS422719A4-7849-4921-AF39-57FF567B483B.html#WSDF962B50-1B1B-461d-9454-7680C953285).

It is possible runtime to achieve the same result ?

```
// ... in a container ...

var father = new SkinnableContainer();
this.addElement(father);

var child = new SkinnableContainer();
// ... some initialization... child is filled with some other elements from outside

father.addElement(child);

// ... now if child.height > father.height 
// I want to add a vertical scrollbar
```

Comment: Can I ask what's the point of doing this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm tryng to understand how to use a scroller from Actionscript without MXML because i'm developing a class which read an XML from a remote host and build a complex interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always put the child in a [`Scroller`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html) control.

For example:

```
var father = new SkinnableContainer();
this.addElement(father);

var scroller = new Scroller();
var child = new SkinnableContainer();
// ... some initialization... child is filled with some other elements from outside

// scroller.addElement(child); // wrong because you cannot add element to a scroller
scroller.viewport = child.contentGroup; // but you can set this to an IViewport

father.addElement(scroller);
father.addElement(child);
```

Comment: For example: "father.addElement(new Scroller().addElement(child))" ? sorry for the syntax. Oh my god... I completely miserunderstood the Scroller component. It's a container not a scrollbar widget!

Comment: @yuri Yep! You could place the `child` `SkinnableContainer`inside the `Scroller` component. Does this get you what you're looking for? I updated my answer with a quick example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287431/flex4-how-to-add-a-child-to-spark-scroller-in-as